# TcpClient ConnectAsync get status

Tags: c#, sockets, task-parallel-library

Is there any way I can get the status of a TcpClient async connection? Using the following code, how can I get the status of the client using the Connected property? I try to establish a remote connection asynchronously but in the same time don't wait more then 5 seconds ...

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient();

Task tsk = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
   client.ConnectAsync(host, port);

   // client.Connect   (this is always false)
});

tsk.Wait(5000);

// client.Connect   (or if I use it here, this is always false)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First off, do not create a new `Task` of your own; this is a bug. `ConnectAsync` already returns a `Task` that represents the connection attempt:

```
var tsk = client.ConnectAsync(host, port);
tsk.Wait(5000);
```

After the wait returns, check the [`IsCompleted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.iscompleted.aspx) property of the task; it will be `true` if and only if the connection was established.

Comment: Another option would be checking is result of `Wait()`.

Comment: @Jon. Your answer is a big eye opener for me. I had always spawned a new Task so I could use await on the returning Task. Pls do you have any reference or good books to point me to so I can further understand the whole concept deeper? Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

No, @Jon is wrong! The `IsCompleted` will just tell you if the task has been completed, it doesn't **not** indicate that the connection has been made. For example, if no server is open on the specific address/port, `IsCompleted` will return `true` anyway... You should check `IsFaulted` instead.

Here is code, that I have put together from pieces of the internet and I have actually **tested**:

```
string address = "127.0.0.1";
int port = 8888;
int connectTimeoutMilliseconds = 1000;

var tcpClient = new TcpClient();
var connectionTask = tcpClient
    .ConnectAsync(address, port).ContinueWith(task => {
        return task.IsFaulted ? null : tcpClient;
    }, TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);
var timeoutTask = Task.Delay(connectTimeoutMilliseconds)
    .ContinueWith<TcpClient>(task => null, TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);
var resultTask = Task.WhenAny(connectionTask, timeoutTask).Unwrap();

var resultTcpClient = resultTask.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
// Or by using `await`:
// var resultTcpClient = await resultTask.ConfigureAwait(false);

if (resultTcpClient != null)
{
    // Connected!
}
else
{
    // Not connected
}
```

Comment: `IsCompleted` will return true when the task is in one of the three final states: `RanToCompletion`, `Faulted`, or `Canceled` so @Jon is right ...

Comment: @EAKTEAM not quite, from what I see, Jon stated that `IsCompleted` = `client.Connected`. The connection `Task` and the connection are not the same thing.

Comment: Why do you make code to execute synchronously (`TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously`, `await resultTask;`)? If the main objective is to make it asynchronous, why you add code to make it synchronous? What am I missing?

Comment: This code deadlocks if you pass in a port that is closed in .net 4.7.1

Comment: @rollsch You are right. And back then in year 2016 I didn't know that. I updated my answer.
Instead of

```resultTask.Wait(); var resultTcpClient = resultTask.Result;```

you need to run

```var resultTcpClient = resultTask.GetAwaiter().GetResult();```

Comment: That won't avoid deadlocks. The real solution since 2012 is to actually use asynchronous code and `await client.ConnectAsync(host, port);`. To cancel, use a CancellationToken, not another task

Comment: Yes this answer is definitely out of date now. The real answer is use async code and await.

Answer (score 2):

`.Result` and `.Wait(...)` are blocking, not asynchronous. The asynchronous way to connect with a timeout is to use a CancellationToken created by a CancellationTokenSource set to trigger after that timeout :

```
var cts=new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
...
await client.ConnectAsync(host,port,cts.Token);
```